# Conditions not working when rendering partial via ajax

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

In my **index.js.erb**

```
$(".div").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('something/some_form')) %>");
```

in **some_form.htm.erb** i have condition which is not working

```
<% if @variable1 == @variable2 %> 
   show something1
<% else %>
   show something2
<% end %>
```

For some reason when my js.erb renders this partial i always have *show something2*. So <% if @variable1 == @variable2 %> condition not working

variable1 and variable2 defined in my controller

How can i make this equal condition work?

Answer (score 0):

Controller variables are not visible within partials. Please, read the [official documentation on partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass those variables along to the partial via the locals:

```
//e.g locals: {variable1: @variable1, variable2: @variable2}

$(".div").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('something/some_form', locals: {variable1: @variable1, variable2: @variable2})) %>");
```

some_form

```
<% if variable1 == variable2 %> 
   show something1
<% else %>
   show something2
<% end %>
```